# value of the index changes after getText() inside a for loop - PROTRACTOR

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, protractor

In the code below, I'm using a repeater to get the values from ng-repeat and getting the column by cat.name which gives me an array of all the cat names. So I'm doing a for loop to get to a particular name, say Meow, I want to store the index value, so that I can validate whether the corresponding row, the cat's age to be equal to 10. The 2 console.log of index inside the for loop results in different values, the first one ranges from 0-10 (considering the length of the array as 10) and the next always results in 10. It logs "10" 10 times. Now, I cannot get the index to validate the corresponding row, since i is always 10. Can someone correct me where I'm going wrong and also answer me with the modified code. I guess I'm going wrong in chaining the promise

```
  element(by.repeater(cat in cats).column(cat.name)).then(function(fields) {
    for (var i in fields) {                // promise returns an array fields
      console.log(i);                      // values range from 0 to length of the fields(say 10)
      fields[i].getText().then(function(fieldValue) {
        console.log(i);                    // values are always 10 (i.e the length of the array)
        if(fieldValue === 'Meow') {
          var catAge= element(by.repeater('cat in cats').row(i)).element(by.model('cat.age')); // row(i) always gives the last value
          expect(catAge.getAttribute('value')).toBe('10');
        }
      })
    }
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: From what I'm seeing, you're both looping and looking for a certain element (text with `Meow`).  Are you aware of the [each()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each) and [filter()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) functions?  Might fix your issue and would also make your code significantly cleaner/more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue come from below snippet, the first console.log() is executed sync, but the second console.log() will be executed async, because it inside `getText().then()`, as we know all Protractor api is async and return a Promise.

```
for (var i in fields) { 
      console.log(i); 
      fields[i].getText().then(function(fieldValue) {
        console.log(i);
```

So the actual execution procedure of above `for` loop should be like this:

```
when i=1
    first console.log() execute done, it print out 1
    fields[i].getText() execute done, it return a Promise,
    and push the promise into Protractor control flow,
    actually getText() not to read the text from page,
    because it's execute async.


when i=2
    first console.log() execute done, it print out 2
    fields[i].getText() execute done, it return a Promise,
    and push the promise into Protractor control flow,
    actually getText() not to read the text from page,
    because it's execute async.

....

when i=10
    the loop end,  
    you get 1, 2 .. 9, 10 printed out
    Protractor control flow get a promise queue
    Now Protractor control flow start to execute the promise queue

    Protractor push out the fist promise in queue
    Important!!! the i=10 now
    fields[i].getText() will be fields[10].getText()
    so you will get fields[10].getText() for 10 times
```

**Option 1)** use javascript closure as Jamines comment said, a little changes on your current code

```
element(by.repeater(cat in cats).column(cat.name)).then(function(fields) {
  for (var i in fields) {
    console.log(i);

    (function(index){ // change part

      fields[index].getText().then(function(fieldValue) {
        console.log(index);  
        if(fieldValue === 'Meow') {
          var catAge= element(by.repeater('cat in cats').row(index)).element(by.model('cat.age'));
          expect(catAge.getAttribute('value')).toBe('10');
        }
      })

    })(i); // change part

  }
});
```

**Option 2** use Protractor `filter()`

```
element(by.repeater(cat in cats).column(cat.name)).then(function(fields) {
  for (var i in fields) {
    console.log(i);
    var matchedIndex = -1;

    fields
      .filter(function(item, index){
        if( matchedIndex > -1) { 
          // means had found the matched one, directly return false to
          // skip read text from page to reduce exection time
          return false;
        }
        else {
          return item.getText().then(function(name){
             if(name === 'Meow') {
               matchedIndex = index;
               return true;
             }
             return false;
          })

        }
      })
      .then(function(){
        console.log('matchedIndex: ' + matchedIndex);  
        var catAge= element(by.repeater('cat in cats').row(matchedIndex)).element(by.model('cat.age'));
        return expect(catAge.getAttribute('value')).toBe('10');
      });
  }
});
```